# Как отключить debug в IDEA: Java + MongoDB

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mongodb

При использовании java с MongoDB постоянно вываливаются эти сообщения (красный цвет).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Их как то можно отключить? А то после создания jar файла и запуска в консоли очень неудобно, так как они и там постоянно пишутся! (Заметьте, это не ошибки, они носят информационный характер)

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй [Grep Console Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console)

До

[image]
После
[image]

Comment: Пробовал, все равно вываливаются постоянно.

Comment: @Николай А если попробовать просто через логгер настроить? `Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver");
logger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);`

Comment: Да, получилось, теперь только 1 сообщение в самом начал при коннекте к удаленной db